# How to set value unchecked to radiobuttonenumfor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I want to set radio button enum  value to unchecked. my code is

```
public enum AgeGroup
    {

        [Display(Name = "20")]
        Twenty, // = "20",
        [Display(Name = "21-30")]
        TwentyOneToThirty, // = "21-30",
        [Display(Name = "31-45")]
        ThirtyOneToFortyFive, // = "31-45",
        [Display(Name = "45-60")]
        FortyFiveToSixty, // = "45-60",
        [Display(Name = "60+")]
        SixtyPlus, // = "60+"
    }
```

My model class is

```
 public AgeGroup AgeGroup { get; set; }
```

and the view is

```
<td>@Html.RadioButtonForEnum(m => m.AgeGroup)/td>
```

When i run the code its showing that value 20 is selected. I dont want anything to be selected. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the value `20` is selected by default because enums are just set to the first value by default. You will have to make the property as nullable on the model like

```
public AgeGroup? AgeGroup { get; set; }
```